# Detailed exception logging on wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, exception

Lately I am working on exception logging module of a WCF service. Unfortunately the service hasn't been introduced with unit tests, therefore there are many unexpected exceptions occurring. And so far I have accomplished to get the exceptions with interceptor aproach, by implementing `IErrorHandler` interface and tying it to the service interface with `IServiceBehaviour`. I liked this functionality very much actually. But it brought me into a next step of desire of getting the details of exception. Like on which line did the exception occurred?

I can satisfy this desire by 2 ways in my mind:

1. By having a variable for keeping track of the lines I've passed through successfully, and including it in the exception thrown.
2. By catching exceptions from all lines seperately.

But both approaches seem very lousy to me. I am wondering is there a known design pattern or a tool to achive this goal?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you might try using logging, such as log4net. Then you can find out where is and what happened. Exception object not always contains the stack info, because of "inlining", that occur during optimization etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will check that tool.

Comment: Just one more tip, In order to use it you have to define a config section <log4net> in your web.config and append the following line in your AssemblyInfo.cs [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]. After that log4net is configured and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

include the PDB files for your service and the line numbers will be included in `exception.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

The way we have solved this problem is twofold:

1. Our services are dumb wrappers around commands. So when a service method is entered it delegates its work to a command.
2. We wrap every command call in a logging proxy that is responsible for logging input, output and errors and executing the command.

For example:

```
public FooServiceModel GetFoo(int fooId)
{
   return new ILogged<GetFooCommand>().Target.Execute(fooId);
}
```

This delegates execution of the command to `ILogged` which:

1. Logs the command name
2. Logs the command parameters
3. Logs the execution result
4. Logs any exceptions

It also does some other stuff to link up the client request with the server call using custom message headers so that a call can be completely debugged from client to server and back. This is incredibly useful and allows us to diagnose even complex problems off site.

We use the [`Castle.Core`](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) dynamic proxy to implement `ILogged` with an interceptor that looks something like this (`ILog` is a log4net logger):

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public LoggingInterceptor([NotNull] object target, [NotNull] ILog logger)
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
        }

        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        }

        this.Target = target;
        this.Logger = logger;
    }

    public object Target { get; set; }

    public ILog Logger { get; set; }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Logger.Debug(invocation);               
            invocation.ReturnValue = invocation.Method.Invoke(
                this.Target, invocation.Arguments);

            this.Logger.Debug("Invocation return value:");
            this.Logger.Debug(invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            this.Logger.Error("Unable to execute invocation", ex);

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The invocation itself is rendered by a custom log4net object renderer:

```
public class InvocationRenderer : IObjectRenderer
{
    public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
    {
        var invocation = (IInvocation)obj;
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendFormat(
            "Invoking Method: {0} --> '{1}' with parameters (", 
            invocation.Method.DeclaringType != null 
               ? invocation.Method.DeclaringType.FullName : "{Unknown Type}",
            invocation.Method);

        var parameters = invocation.Method
            .GetParameters()
            .Zip(invocation.Arguments, (p, a) => new { Parameter = p, Argument = a })
            .ToArray();
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat(
                "{0}: {1}", 
                parameter.Parameter.Name, 
                rendererMap.FindAndRender(parameter.Argument));

            if (++index < parameters.Length)
            {
                builder.Append(", ");
            }
        }

        builder.Append(")");

        writer.Write(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Hopefully that will give you some ideas on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: I don't have any experience with log4net tool, so I will look into it then I can approach the solution with your suggestion maybe. Let me first have a grasp on log4net.